# Misunderstanding lifecycle hooks VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting a tuto on the framework Vue.JS.

I m using the life cycle **created** of the Vue. I thought that this function was called once the vue is created. But in this example, 
A behavior that I do not understand.

```
<template>
  <div class="game">
    <span class="round"  v-on:click="clickOnRound" v-on:click.alt="bonus"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'game',
    created: function () {
      console.log('On Vue created')
      document.onkeydown = this.start
    },
    methods: {
      clickOnRound: function (event) {
        console.log('Click')
      },
      bonus: function (event) {
        console.log('Click + alt')
        console.log(event)
      },
      start: function (event) {
        console.log('Start called')
        console.log(event)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I type a letter on the keyboard, *the function start is called, without calling the function of created.*

Here the console output:

- On Vue created
- Start called
- Start called
- Start called
- Start called

I can t understand how the start function is called without calling each time the created function , *because the start function is inside the created function.*

```
 created: function () {
      console.log('On Vue created')
      document.onkeydown = this.start
    },
```

Comment: It sounds more like you're misunderstanding the way web platform events work. `document.onkeydown = this.start` only assigns an event handler to the "keydown" event. Where this happens is not relevant to the execution of the start function, once the keydown event is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) block will be only called once when the vue instance is created, thats why you are seeing log : `On Vue created` only once.

Why are you see `Start called` on each key pressed: because you have registered `this.start` on [document.onkeydown](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/documentonkeydown.htm), so on each key press, `this.start` will get executed.

Comment: Vue 3 comes with renamed hooks, find detailed explanation [here](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085)